# Error importing class to another file with python

Tags: python, class, object, import, instantiation

I am learning python at the moment
the task is this;
Write a program that reads pet information (name, type and age) from a file (called animals.txt) and creates Pet objects (using the information stored in the animals.txt file).  Store Pet objects in a list called animals.

**animal.txt**

```
ralph, dog, 3
buster, cat, 8
sammy, bird, 5
mac, dog, 1
coco, cat, 6
```

My class file i created is called 
**pet.py**

```
class Pet:
    # The __init__ method initializes the data attributes of the Profile class
    def __init__(self, name ='', animal_type = '', age = ''):
        self.__name = name
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.age = 0

    def __str__(self):
        string = self.__name + ' ' + self.__animal_type + ' ' + self.age
        return string

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_animal_type(self, breed):
        self.__animal_type = breed

    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def set_age(self, old):
        self.age = old    

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age
```

I then want to use this class in a file 
**animals.py**

```
import pet

animals = [] // create a list 

infile = open("animals.txt", "r") // open the file

lines = infile.readlines() // read all lines into list

## add each pet object
for line in lines:
    data = line.split(",")
    animals.append(pet.set_name(data[0]))
    animals.append(pet.set_animal_type(data[1]))
    animals.append(pet.set_age(data[2]))

infile.close()
```

I am getting an error

> pet.set_name [pylint] E1101 : module 'pet' has no 'set_name' member.

If i do this code below in the class file **pet.py** I don't get the error

```
pet = Pet()
name = "thing"
breed = "dog"
pet.set_name(name)
pet.set_animal_type(breed)
pet.set_age(10)
print(pet)
```

and it returns as expected

> thing dog 10

Why wont the **animals.py** file allow me to use the class i have imported?

I have tried pet=Pet() but it has

> error E0602: undefined variable 'Pet'

Comment: `from pet import Pet` then use `Pet` as you did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your animals.py file `pet` represents a module. You need to extract the class located within that module like this:

```
import pet

myPet = pet.Pet()
```

Comment: TY .. this did work and i see what i did wrong there :-)  I am now meant to append this data to the animal list .. I thought i would do this with --> animals.append(myPet) although the output with print(animals) is --> <pet.Pet object at 0x000001B110E89B00> repeated 5 times .. when I use print(myPet) with each iteration the details are correct but not able to append the same object to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're importing the entire `pet` module's contents. You can gain access to the `Pet` class in one of two ways.

The first requires you to use the object's entire dotted path

```
import pet

pet.Pet(...)
```

The second requires you to import the `Pet` class

```
from pet import Pet

Pet(...)
```

One gotcha here is that depending on your folder structure, Python may not be able to identify your file as importable, so you may need to create a blank file named `__init__.py` at the same position in your directory structure as `pet.py`.